# What's the difference between @property and @X.getter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to research this question in python docs and other blogs, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. So here we go. In the following code:

```
class C:
    _x = "Hola"
    @property
    def X(self): return self._x
    @X.getter
    def X(self): return self._x
```

I understand the first decorator `@property` defines the property. Is the `@X.getter` redundant in this case? When are both methods necessary?

Comment: That code doesn't make sense.

Comment: `X.getter` only works because you have defined `X` beforehand. given that `X` is a function already what is the point of that?

Comment: It's not redundant exactly, it adds a *second* getter named `C`. But the behaviour is the same as if you'd just written `@property` again.

Comment: @user2357112, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@property` creates a property with the decorated function as its getter (and with the decorated function's docstring as its docstring).

`@X.getter`, where `X` is an existing property, creates a *new* property with the old property's setter, deleter, and docstring, but with the decorated function as its getter.

`getter` mostly exists for symmetry with `setter` and `deleter`, which create copies of a property with a new setter or deleter respectively. The intended use case for those methods looks like

```
class Whatever:
    @property
    def blah(self):
        "docstring for blah"
        # logic to get property
    @blah.setter
    def blah(self, value):
        # logic to set property
    @blah.deleter
    def blah(self):
        # logic to delete property
```

where a property is built up with a getter, setter, and deleter by use of `@blah.setter` and `@blah.deleter`, and each decorated function definition replaces the old property with a new, more complete property.

What you're doing is extremely unusual and doesn't really make sense. You create one property for the `X` attribute with one getter, and then you use `@X.getter` to replace it with a different property with a different, equivalent getter (but the old getter's docstring, which would matter if the two getter functions didn't both have `None` docstrings). There's no point in doing that.

Comment: I know it's unusual. I wrote the code for the propose of this question. ;-)

Comment: There was an error in the code, can you check it please?

Comment: Answer modified.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the @X.getter redundant in this case? When are both methods necessary?

The getter is completely redundant and unnecessary. The normal use of reaccessing X is to configure the setter and deleter, the getter is configured via `@property` already.

Answer (score -3):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

> A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as
>   decorators that create a copy of the property with the corresponding
>   accessor function set to the decorated function. This is best
>   explained with an example: